# Hybridauth - Can not login with Windows Live

Tags: php, hybridauth, windows-live

I am working on a simple PHP site and trying to integrate social login in it. So I used [Hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) library. To login via Windows Live account, I created a new app at [here](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/create). And in redirect URL, I entered full domain name such as http://mydomain.com because Live does not accept query string in its redirect URL

Here is my config.php

```
array(
    "base_url" => "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->base . "/hybridauth/", 

    "providers" => array ( 

        // windows live
        "Live" => array ( 
            "enabled" => false,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "xxxxxxxxx", "secret" => "xxxxxxxxx" ) 
        ), 
    ),

    "debug_mode" => false,

    "debug_file" => ""
);
```

When I click the login link

```
<a href="loginwith/live" class="zocial live">Login with Windows Live</a>
```

I am directed to the link

[https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1066#error=invalid_request&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20'redirect_uri'%20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20expected%20value%20is%20'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'%20or%20a%20URL%20which%20matches%20the%20redirect%20URI%20registered%20for%20this%20client%20application.](https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1066#error=invalid_request&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20%27redirect_uri%27%20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20expected%20value%20is%20%27https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf%27%20or%20a%20URL%20which%20matches%20the%20redirect%20URI%20registered%20for%20this%20client%20application.)

with error message "We're unable to complete your request Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later."

I tried to change Redirect URL but the result is same. Can someone fix this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"enabled" => true,
```